# Disguising the use of Game Center

Tags: game-center, gamekit

We are developing a multiuser app that is not really a game.  We want to use the GameKit framework to use the matchmaking and GKVoiceChat.  But we want to avoid the Game Center login (my understanding is that this is not possible) and especially the welcome banners.  Or at least to change them. Is there any way to suppress or change the banners?  And are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually very new to this. But while I was researching online for the same reason, I found both this question and one tutorial. This tutorial is seems to be old and it is for **iOS5**. But hopefully GameKit still functions the same way.

It is a game that uses GameKit for communication but did not use Game Center:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/12735/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-1

Above is the link for the first part where he explained that he uses Game Kit but not Game Center. You can find the entire tutorial by search the keyword **Bluetooth** in this page:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials